# Vim does not recognize previous command when issued within a function

Tags: vim

I can execute the following command in Vim and then enter `@:` to repeat the command. This works fine:

```
:windo silent/foo/|wincmd w
@:
```

However, when I execute the same command within a function, `@:` displays an error message saying there is no previous command. How can I get the command within the function to be registered as a command for `@:`?

```
function! Find_In_Multiple_Windows(pattern)
  if !empty(a:pattern)
    execute ":windo silent /" . a:pattern . "/|wincmd w"
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent>fw :call Find_In_Multiple_Windows(input("Search for:"))<CR>
```

```
fw
Search for: foo
@:
E30: No previous command line
```

Comment: Update: The first "@:" should be on  a separate line. My formatting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
execute ":windo silent /" . a:pattern . "/|wincmd w"
```

with

```
call feedkeys(":windo silent /" . a:pattern . "/|wincmd w\n", "t")
```

which will literally type the command to the command line and execute it, and so the command will be stored to `@:`.